# Не работает slideToggle

Tags: jquery

Почему не срабатывает? 
И можно ли таким способом добиться такого же эффекта http://lukasz-developer.com/codecanyon/menu1/index.html

https://jsfiddle.net/atomr/kv45dj0t/

```
(function() {
  $('#nav__btn').click(function() {
    $('nav__nav').slideToggle('slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подключите **jquery** + исправьте `$('nav__nav')` на `$('.nav__nav')` (точку потеряли)!

```js
$('#nav__btn').click(function() {
  $('.nav__nav').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <ul class="nav__nav">
    <li class="nav__item nav__active">
      <a class="nav__home" href="#">
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__website" href="#">
        <span>Isuzu Website</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__isis" href="#">
        <span>ISIS</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__power" href="#">
        <span>Truck Power</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__sheets" href="#">
        <span>Spec Sheets</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__images" href="#">
        <span>Images</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__video" href="#">
        <span>Video</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__survey" href="#">
        <span>Online Survey</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__blog" href="#">
        <span>Blog</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav__item">
      <a class="nav__contact" href="#">
        <span>Contact</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#" class="nav__btn" id="nav__btn">Menu</a>
</div>
```

Comment: точно, блин) спасибо большое)

Comment: @Atomrr, не за что))

Comment: Любой код с методом slideToggle, выводит ошибку. Замена этого метода на toggleClass решает проблему..